# How to add Newsletter optin to a checkout step in the shippingAddress block

Tags: magento2, checkout, newsletter

I wish to add an optional newsletter during the checkout process in Magento 2( at the time of encoding the delivery address)

I think we need to update `checkout_index_index.xml` by overriding in the theme

but my knowledge ends there. Would someone kindly please explain to me how?

Answer (score 2):

There is a free module available called Subscribe at Checkout:

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-module-subscribe-at-checkout.html